# Create tabs using mootools

Tags: mootools

How to create three tabs using mootools ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function mootab(_nav, _body) {
    var tabs = $(_nav).getElements('a');
    var containers = _body.getElements('li');

    tabs.each(function(tab, index) {
        tab.addEvents({
            click: function(event) {
                event.stop();

                tabs.removeClass('active');
                tabs[index].addClass('active');

                containers.removeClass('active');
                containers[index].addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
}

mootab($('tabs-nav'),$('tabs-body'))
```

The following example is more reusable: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/insign/f5k9f/)

Comment: cool. question is a bit ambiguous, though :) all the OP had to do was do a google search...

Comment: Some people don't know how to use Google, apparently :-)